# Wifi(internet) does not work when bluetooth headset set to HSP/HPF mode

Tags: 18.04, wireless, bluetooth, internet

Ubuntu:18.04

May laptop is connected to internet through WiFi

Then when I connect my bluetooth earphone and set the Sound profile to `High Fidelity Playback(A2Dp Sink)`, the internet works fine

Results from speedtest.net with A2DP profile

[image: Results from speedtest.net]

The moment I switch to `Headset Head Unit(HSP/HFP)`, the internet just stops working

As evident by
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ue1Oh.png Speedtest downlaod fails

**Edit 1:**
Output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; lsusb`

```
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros QCA9377 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [168c:0042] (rev 31)
    Subsystem: Lite-On Communications Inc QCA9377 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [11ad:08a6]
    Kernel driver in use: ath10k_pci
    Kernel modules: ath10k_pci
04:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8411B PCI Express Card Reader [10ec:5287] (rev 01)
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0bda:57f2 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 04ca:3015 Lite-On Technology Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 04d9:a0ac Holtek Semiconductor, Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

**Edit 2:**
One thing that I have observed is that , **the internet doesn't just stop working. It works for 5 seconds then it stops for another 5 seconds and this cycle continues**

Maybe its because the bluetooth does not let wifi data passed for sometime or hogs 2.4Ghz all for itself

**Edit 3:**
Output of `grep ath /etc/modprobe.d/*`

```
/etc/modprobe.d/ath10k.conf:options ath9k btcoex_enable=1
/etc/modprobe.d/ath9k.conf:options ath9k btcoex_enable=0
/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-ath_pci.conf:# which ath5k cannot recover. To prevent this condition, stop
/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-ath_pci.conf:blacklist ath_pci
```

**Edit 4**
I deleted the `/etc/modprobe.d/ath10k.conf` and `/etc/modprobe.d/ath9k.conf` files as suggested by @Pilot6 but still same problem

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; lsusb` terminal command.

Comment: @Pilot6 Added the output of the command

Comment: Does your laptop have a physical toggle switch to enable/disable the radio? If so, have you tried toggling off, connecting the headset in HSP, then toggling the wireless back on?

Comment: @justus95 Yes my laptop has a physical wireless enable/disable switch, I'll try it and post my results here later tonight

Comment: @justus95 The physical switch is of  airplane mode, and it stops bluetooth along with wifi

Comment: @Pilot6 added an interesting finding as edit 2, maybe it helps for solving my problem

Comment: That may be the problem. But it is unlikely with Atheros devices. Please add output of `grep ath /etc/modprobe.d/*` to check if some wrong options are set.

Comment: @Pilot6 added the output.
Does `ath9k` and `ath10k` in the output means I have 2 different driver versions installed?

Comment: This is the problem. You tried wrong things. I am writing an answer.